# Validar tamanho máximo de um anexo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

Boa Tarde galera,

Preciso validar o tamanho máximo de um anexo porém meu código não está funcionando, podem me ajudar?

Segue o código abaixo:

HTML:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AdicionarAnexo", "Turma", FormMethod.Post, new { @encoding = "multipart/form-data", @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "AnexoTurmaForm" }))
            {
                <input type="file" name="anexo" id="idAnexo" data-max-size="5" />
                <input type="button" id="adicionarAnexo" value="Incluir anexo" onclick="teste()"/>
            }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function teste() {
    var fileInput = $('#idAnexo');
    var maxSize = fileInput.data('data-max-size');
    $('#AnexoTurmaForm').button(function (e) {
        if (fileInput.get(0).files.length) {
            var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
            if (fileSize > maxSize) {
                alert('file size is more then' + maxSize + ' bytes');
                return false;
            } else {
                alert('file size is correct- ' + fileSize + ' bytes');
            }
        } else {
            alert('choose file, please');
            return false;
        }

    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente utiliza o evento [.change()](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=change()&oq=change()&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1272j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=change()%20jquery) e verificar se ele possui um valor maior que o `data-max-size`. Ficaria assim o seu código:

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("input:file").change(function () {//ou Id do input 
            var fileInput = $(this);
            var maxSize = $(this).data('max-size');
            console.log(fileInput.get(0).files[0].size);

            //aqui a sua função normal
            if (fileInput.get(0).files.length) {
                var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
                if (fileSize > maxSize) {
                    alert('file size is more then' + maxSize + ' bytes');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    alert('file size is correct- ' + fileSize + ' bytes');
                }
            } else {
                alert('choose file, please');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Veja um exemplo no <kbd>[JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/hyxjak7n/)</kbd>

Caso queira o evento ao clicar no botão, basta alterar para isso:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
            $("#adicionarAnexo").click(function () {
                var fileInput = $('#idAnexo');
                var maxSize = $('#idAnexo').data('max-size');
                console.log(fileInput.get(0).files[0].size);

                //aqui a sua função normal
                if (fileInput.get(0).files.length) {
                    var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
                    if (fileSize > maxSize) {
                        alert('file size is more then' + maxSize + ' bytes');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        alert('file size is correct- ' + fileSize + ' bytes');
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('choose file, please');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Veja o exemplo no <kbd>[JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/hyxjak7n/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Perfeito, me ajudou muito, obrigado!